# Defining an Output type for typescrpit which prevents mistaking an Output argument as Input

Tags: typescript

This might be already defined, I got this idea from C#. I would like to write the following:

```
type FunctionOutput<T> = T; // This is my naive implementation, which doesn't fulfill its purpose.
type Result = {result: number};

function myFun(a: number, b: number, c: FunctionOutput<Result>)
{
   c.result = a + b;
}

c: Result = {};
// How should I define FunctionOutput type so that the following call gives an error
myFun(1, 2, c) // This should give Error: c is not of type FunctionOutput<Result>

// This would enforce calling the function as follows:
myFun(1, 2, c as FunctionOutput<Result>);
console.log(c.result);   // Outputs 3
```

With this I want to achieve making very clear at the function call that the 3rd argument is an output, and I don't want that the user is able to call this 3rd parameter thinking it is an input argument. The question is:

How should I define this `FunctionOutput` type?

Comment: What is wrong with the code in your question, if you just use the Result type?

Comment: It wouldn't fail in the case myFun(1,2,c). I want it to yield an error if the passed type is not an FunctionOutput<T> type. I've updated the question to try to make it clearer @kaya3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has [structural types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), so generally for one type to be unassignable to another it must have a property the other doesn't have. If you want a type like `FunctionOutput<T>` to only be usable with a type assertion `c as ...` then you can give it a property which no real value will ever have; for example:

```
type FunctionOutput<T> = T & { __brand: 'FunctionOutput' }
```

The `c` object of course will not really have the `__brand` property at runtime, but you will never actually access that property, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was hoping for. Thank you very much for the explanation and example